# inherit base class's constructor

Tags: c++

For the following code:

```cpp
struct Base
{
protected:
    Base(){}
    Base(int) {}
};


struct Derive : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
};


int main()
{
    Derive d1;
    Derive d2(3);
}
```

Seems d1 can be constructed correctly, but d2 cannot be constructed.

SO my question is: Why `using Base::Base` can only change the default constructor to public and keep the constructor with a int parameter as protected?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `using Base::Base` doesn't make the default constructor of `Base` public, remove it and you will still get the [same result](https://godbolt.org/z/KW4MMh8Ke).

Comment: Constructors are never inherited. A base class constructor can't possibly know how to construct the derived class, because any useful derived class is structurally different from the base.

Comment: Not according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: This has nothing to do with `using Base::Base`.    Rules of the language allow a default (no-argument) constructor of `Derive` to be implicitly generated, if default constructors for all bases and members are available and accessible.   Since `Base::Base()` is accessible to the derived class, `Derive::Derive()` can be implicitly generated.    There is no such rule for implicitly generating `Derive::Derive(int)`,  so `Derive` does not have a constructor that accepts an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) makes the `Base` constructors visible for overload resolution but with the same accessibility that the constructor has in the base class.

> If the using-declaration refers to a constructor of a direct base of the class being defined (e.g. `using Base::Base;`), all constructors of that base (ignoring member access) are made visible to overload resolution when initializing the derived class.
>
> If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, **it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored.**

`Base::Base(int)` is still `protected` in `Derive`, not `public`.

It's not clear to me why `Derive::Derive()` works, however. Apparently the using-declaration doesn't count as a user-declared constructor, meaning that it still has the implicitly-declared default constructor which is `public`. Therefore, it is preferred in overload resolution to the base class constructor introduced by your using declaration:

> As with using-declarations for any other non-static member functions, if an inherited constructor matches the signature of one of the constructors of `Derived`, it is hidden from lookup by the version found in `Derived`.

Comment: "The using-declaration doesn't count as a user-declared constructor, meaning that it still has the implicitly-declared default constructor which is public". This is not correct. If you place a cout in base class constructor, you will see that your base class constructor is getting called.

Comment: @kadina That doesn't prove what you think it proves, because the implicitly-declared default constructor calls the default constructor for all base classes. And inside the body of a constructor for `Derive`, `Base::Base()` is accessible because it's `protected` not `private`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send parameters to base class constructor, you need to send the parameters through derived class constructor only.

using in your code is no use like below. Below function works fine.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
protected:
    Base() {}
    Base(int) {}
};


struct Derive : public Base
{
public:
    //using Base::Base;
};


int main()
{
    Derive d1;
    //Derive d2(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I didn't use 'using'. But as I am not passing any parameters to 'd1' object, through derived class default constructor, base class constructor (constructor with no arguments) will be called. But if you want to send parameters to base class, you need to send it through derived class only like below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
protected:
    Base() {}
    Base(int y) {};
};


struct Derive : public Base
{
public:
    Derive()
    {
        
    };
    
    Derive(int x) : Base(x) {
    }
};


int main()
{
    Derive d1;
    Derive d2(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Derive() = default;` is better than an empty constructor. It requires C++11, but it's a decade old at this point.

Comment: This seems to contradict what https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration says.